# WebGL / GLSL: How to set background color of embedded x-shader/x-fragment?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, glsl, webgl

--

Pardon, I'm new to GLSL ... I'm trying to achieve something I thought would be simple, but can't solve after a lot of reading.

I have the below `x-shader/x-fragment` which animates some swirling colors on a black `rgb(0, 0, 0)` background. I have it embedded in some `html` within a `<canvas>` element.

I just wanted to **change the background** to a lighter black `rgb(32, 32, 32)`

How do I achieve this?

(changing the CSS background color of `<canvas>` tag or container `div` had no effect.

You can see the live animation / output of the code here:

http://glslsandbox.com/e#25366.0

... and here is the code:

```
<script id="fragment" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  //
  // pulsing blobs

  precision mediump float;

  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 resolution;


  //.h
  vec3 sim(vec3 p,float s);
  vec2 rot(vec2 p,float r);
  vec2 rotsim(vec2 p,float s);
  vec2 zoom(vec2 p,float f);

  vec2 makeSymmetry(vec2 p){
     vec2 ret=p;
     ret=rotsim(ret,sin(time*0.9)*2.0+3.0);


     ret.x=abs(ret.x);
     return ret;
  }

  float makePoint(float x,float y,float fx,float fy,float sx,float sy,float t){
     float xx=x+tan(t*fx)*sy;
     float yy=y-tan(t*fy)*sy;
     float a=0.5/sqrt(abs(abs(x*xx)+abs(yy*y)));
     float b=0.5/sqrt(abs(x*xx+yy*y));
     return a*b;
  }

  // utility functions
  const float PI=3.14159265;

  vec3 sim(vec3 p,float s){
     vec3 ret=p;
     ret=p+s/2.0;
     ret=fract(ret/s)*s-s/4.0;
     return ret;
  }

  vec2 rot(vec2 p,float r){
     vec2 ret;
     ret.x=p.x*sin(r)*cos(r)-p.y*cos(r);
     ret.y=p.x*cos(r)+p.y*sin(r);
  return p;
     return ret;
  }

  vec2 rotsim(vec2 p,float s){
     vec2 ret=p;
     ret=rot(p,-PI/(s*2.0));
     ret=rot(p,floor(atan(ret.x,ret.y)/PI*s)*(PI/s));
     return ret;
  }

  vec2 zoom(vec2 p,float f){
      return vec2(p.x*f,p.y*f);
  }
  // utility stuff end


  void main( void ) {

     vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution.y-vec2((resolution.x/resolution.y)/2.0,0.5);

     p=rot(p,sin(time+length(p))*1.0);
     p=zoom(p,sin(time*2.0)*0.5+0.8);

     p=p*2.0;

     float x=p.x;
     float y=p.y;

     float t=time*0.5;

     float a=
         makePoint(x,y,3.3,2.9,0.3,0.3,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,1.9,2.0,0.4,0.4,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,0.8,0.7,0.4,0.5,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,2.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,0.8,1.7,0.5,0.4,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,0.3,1.0,0.4,0.4,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,1.4,1.7,0.4,0.5,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,1.3,2.1,0.6,0.3,t);
     a=a+makePoint(x,y,1.8,1.7,0.5,0.4,t);

     float b=
         makePoint(x,y,1.2,1.9,0.3,0.3,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,0.7,2.7,0.4,0.4,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,1.4,0.6,0.4,0.5,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,2.6,0.4,0.6,0.3,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,0.7,1.4,0.5,0.4,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,0.7,1.7,0.4,0.4,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.5,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,1.4,0.9,0.6,0.3,t);
     b=b+makePoint(x,y,0.7,1.3,0.5,0.4,t);

     float c=
         makePoint(x,y,3.7,0.3,0.3,0.3,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,1.9,1.3,0.4,0.4,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.5,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,1.2,1.7,0.6,0.3,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.4,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,1.4,0.8,0.4,0.5,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,0.2,0.6,0.6,0.3,t);
     c=c+makePoint(x,y,1.3,0.5,0.5,0.4,t);

     vec3 d=vec3(a,b,c)/31.0;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(d.x,d.y,d.z,1.0);
  }
</script>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just put clearColor in your render() function after every gl.clear:

```
gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

Also be carefull how you create the gl context from canvas.
For the moment you have this;

```
gl = canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
```

Change to something like this to ensure that alpha from browser is enabled

```
gl = canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true, premultipliedAlpha:true} );
```

Comment: This will not work as the shader outputs rgba(0,0,0,1.)

Comment: It doesn't matter what color you give in shader, there will be an alpha multiplication. just clear the color with a value between 0 and 1.0 to see.

Comment: alpha is the default for WebGL. You don't need to do anything to enabled it. You can only choose to disable it. It's on by default and it expects premultipliedAlpha by default

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the output of your shader like:

```
vec3 d=max(vec3(a,b,c)/31.0,vec3(1./255.)*32.);
gl_FragColor = vec4(d,1.0);
```

`max` acts component wise and returns the larger value of given argument components effectively clamping your darkest color to 0.125 (1/255*32).